# How can I read a csv.gz file with pyarrow from a file object?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, pyarrow

I am trying to read a bunch of gzip-compressed csv files from S3 using pyarrow.
The documentation page of [`pyarrow.csv.read_csv`](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.csv.read_csv.html#pyarrow.csv.read_csv) says

> If a string or path, and if it ends with a recognized compressed file extension (e.g. “.gz” or “.bz2”

Unfortunately, I cannot provide a string value as the input path, so the CSV reader assumes no compression.

```
import s3fs
import pyarrow.csv as pv

s3 = s3fs.core.S3FileSystem(anon=False)

csv_path = 's3://bucket_name/path/to/file.csv.gz'

with s3.open(csv_path) as s3fp:
    table = pv.read_csv(s3fp)
```

I tried to dig deeper into pyarrow internals but I wasn't able to identify a way to pass an additional argument for compression type.

Comment: At the moment, reading compressed files only works when passing an actual path to a local file. So your workaround is fine, but I opened an issue to track a possible enhancement to enable this: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-10425

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a workaround for it. It is possible to add a gzip decompression in between before reading the csv from the file handler:

```
import gzip
import s3fs
import pyarrow.csv as pv

s3 = s3fs.core.S3FileSystem(anon=False)

csv_path = 's3://bucket_name/path/to/file.csv.gz'

with s3.open(csv_path) as s3fp:
    with gzip.open(s3fp) as fp:
        table = pv.read_csv(fp)
```